# Is it possible to change the default `node navigation type` when browsing Architecture Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, architecture, navigation

Whenever we click on a node, the *node navagation type*, i.e. the parts marked in red in below screenshot, is always `Calls`. I prefer it to be `Calls` and `All inbound` (so that I can select its containing class/namespace etc.).

Is it possible to do that? Please share.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to figure this out? If you move your pointer over the bar where it says "Calls", you can expand it and select different elements and actions. So you can then also select "All Inbound" so that it filters the next column using both criteria. For more info, see the topic ["How to: Find Code Using Architecture Explorer"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409431.aspx#RefineQuery).